# Where did Credence get this animal?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-beasts, the-crimes-of-grindelwald

I don't know if i missed it somehow, but where in *Fantastic Beasts: The Crimes of Grindelwald* did Credence get the baby

> Phoenix

from? Was there a scene where it came to him? Or did Grindelwald give/plant it to him?

This animal coming or being given to Credence makes a lot of difference to who Credence really is (him being from a certain family or him being manipulated by Grindelwald for his ulterior motives)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We didn't see this bird in the *Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them* and in CoG we only see it in the house where Grimmson kills that servant who put him to adoption.

So, this is obvious that that bird only appeared at that house and Credence starts to take care of it. Later it is revealed that that bird is phoenix and came to him when he was in need.

Now, there are two things here. Either Credence is really a brother of Albus and phoenix came to him in need or it was an illusion of Grindelwald. Both are speculation until JK clarifies it or next movie comes.

Comment: _"in CoG we only see it in the house where Grimmson kills that servant who put him to adoption."_ Are you sure I can't remember a phoenix in that scene and the original screenplay makes no mention of one?

Comment: It was actually a bird that turned out to be a phoenix in the end. If you remember there appears a bird like sparrow.

Comment: Oh that bird, I forgot about that small scene. I'm pretty sure that isn't at Irma's house though.

Comment: I remember vice-versa.

Comment: The scene is noted to take place in ___"EXT. DERELICT BUILDING, ROOFTOP—LATE AFTERNOON"___ which would imply this certainly isn't Irma's house.

Comment: Can you give me the link to that screenplay? I'd happily correct it

Comment: I don't have a... _viable_... link shall we say.